# Combinatorics : Possible rolls on two 6-sided Dice - Difference criteria

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am having a hard time getting the calculation for number of possible dice rolls that meet a criteria for a problem that is defined as such:

*You have two separate 6-sided dice, how many rolls are possible in which the individual die values differ by at most 2?*

My thought process is that you would throw the two dice: $d_1$,$d_2$ one after another. Looking the at value of $d_1$

$d_1 = 1 → d_2 = {1 \lor 2 \lor 3}$

*This would be **3** possibilities*

$d_1 = 2 → d_2 = 1 \lor 2 \lor 3 \lor 4$

*This would be **4** possibilities*

$d_1 = 3 → d_2 = 1 \lor 2 \lor 3 \lor 4 \lor 5$

*This would be **5** possibilities*

$d_1 = 4 → d_2 = 2 \lor 3 \lor 4 \lor 5 \lor 6$

*This would be **5** possibilities*

$d_1 = 5 → d_2 = 3 \lor 4 \lor 5 \lor 6$

*This would be **4** possibilities*

$d_1 = 6 → d_2 =  4 \lor 5 \lor 6$

*This would be **3** possibilities*

$\therefore 3+4+5+5+4+3 = $**24** *possibilities*

However I am being told this is incorrect, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The sample space can be abbreviated as:

```
11 12 13 14 15 16
21 22 23 24 25 26
31 32 33 34 35 36
41 42 43 44 45 46
51 52 53 54 55 56
51 62 63 64 65 66
```

I see a 'partial diagonal' with differences of exactly $2$: `31 42 53 64`.
What else do you see? Count.

Comment: There are 2 diagonals of length 4 with difference 2, 2 diagonals of length 5 with difference 1 and 1 diagonal of length 6 with difference 0, and $ 4(2)+5(2)+6=24$ so didn't he do this right?

Comment: If the question means _absolute_ differences, Yes. If one die is red and the other is green and these are green-minus-red differences, then No.

Comment: Oh right, OP can you clarify if you have more context?

Comment: This is my professor saying it is incorrect; I have no other prompts other than the original "two seperate 6-sided dice". So let's assume they mean _absolute_ difference and that one dice is green and one is red, how does this affect the calculation?

Comment: I think you need to get an explanation of this unclear problem from your professor.